# Mongooses - How to get the data changes in the past two weeks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Supposed I have a book schema. It has few fields.

```
const Book = new schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  like: Number
});
```

How to get the book which get the most like in the past 2 weeks?
Most at all, it need to updated daily.

For example, supposed that i only need likes in the past two day now. **5** people like the book totally on Day1, **7** people like the book on Day2, and **3** people on Day3. Hence, I expect **12 likes (5 + 7) on Day2**, and **10 likes on Day3 (7+3)**

I intend to add a field and to a 14-element array.

```
{
  ...,
  likeCnt: {
    type: Array,
    default: Array(14).fill(0)
  }
}
```

So only update the `Date().getDate() % 14`th element when someone likes the book.

However, I need to use a cron-job to zero every book's `likeCnt[]` everyday.
Please tell me a more efficient solution.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new array where I would keep the date of every change that happens to data.

```
{
  ...,
  likes: [Date],
}
```

Then request it that way to get the last two weeks change:

```
collection.find({
  likes: {
    $gte: Date.now() - 1209600000,
  },
});
```

---

This soluce are going to make you to keep the data even after the two weeks.

You can either remove them periodically, or keep it and allow you to maybe change your functionality later. What if next month you need data on 3 weeks? Always think generic and evolutive.

Comment: Do you mean saving the data like this? `likes:[{Date.now - 2days: 123, Date.now -1day: 321, Date.now: 456}]`

Comment: I mean to just save the timestamp of when the like happens

Comment: It's my bad. I want to get the amount of likes within two weeks. For example, supposed that i only need likes in the past two day now.  5 people like the book totally on Day1, 7 people like the book on Day2, and 3 people on Day3. Hence, on Day2, I expect **12 likes (5 + 7)**, and **10 likes on Day3 (7+3)**